# VLC Extension, storing last played song in a variable not working

Tags: lua, vlc

I am trying to write a small VLC Extension in Lua, which removes the last played item from the playlist, however I have never worked with Lua.

The problem I have is, that the program doesn't store the correct id of the last played item in the variable last.
When I press the next button, both the current and the last item are being removed:

```
function descriptor()
  return {
    title = "My Extension",
    version = "0.1",
    capabilities = { "playing-listener", "input-listener" }
  }
end

function activate()
end

function deactivate()
end

function meta_changed()
end

function playing_changed()
end

function input_changed()
  if last then
    vlc.playlist.delete(last)
  end
  last = vlc.playlist.current()
end
```

Comment: Have you printed the value of `last` in the `input_changed` function when you use it? Does it have the correct value there?

Comment: Thx, I printed some debug messages and as it turned out the input_changed() function is being called more than one time, though the playlist-item only changed one time. With the following change, everything seems to work now: `if last and last ~= vlc.playlist.current() then`

Comment: That sounds like an answer you can write up an accept. Extra good if you can include links to the documentation for `input_changed` which (hopefully) indicate that this is how it is called. (I tried looking quickly. I can't find anything.)